# Obtaining the probability density function from moment generating function

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions, density-function

Currently I'm trying to approach a question whereby I am trying to obtain the Probability Density Function from the Moment Generating Function as follow:
$$M_Y(t)=\left(\frac{e^t-1}{t} \right)^2$$

It looks like a uniform distribution with b=1 and a=0 but with the square being there, I am unable to proceed from here.
$$M(t)=\frac{e^{tb}-e^{ta}}{t(b-a)} $$

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

-Kevin-

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Given independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, the moment generating function of $Z=X+Y$ is $$M_Z(t)=M_X(t)M_Y(t)$$
where $M_X(t)$ and $M_Y(t)$ are the moment generating function of $X$ and $Y$.

What should we do with the pdf of two independent random variables to get the  pdf of their sum?

Comment: +1 Thank you for the quick response. :)

From here, I have obtained that both X and Y are independent uniform over [0,1]. But does that mean that the PDF of Z is the sum of the PDF of X and Y, giving the PDF of Z to be 1/(b-a) + 1/(b-a) = 2/(b-a) ?

Pretty sure I am wrong here.

Comment: @Kevin The pdf of sum of two independent random variables is the *convolution*  of the two pdf. You will have a triangular function in this problem as the convolution of two rectangular functions.